# Is the inverse of an invertible real matrix always a real matrix?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

If yes, then why?

For example you can multiply real matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2&2 \\ 3&3 \end{pmatrix}$ and complex matrix  $\begin{pmatrix} i&1 \\ -i&1 \end{pmatrix}$ together and obtain real matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&4 \\ 0&6 \end{pmatrix}$. Could you find a real matrix and a complex matrix that multiply together to give the identity matrix?

Comment: Do you remember the explicit formula for the inverse? Reciprocal of the determinant times the adjugate transpose? Your answer should be there

Comment: I haven't learned this formula, sorry. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Calculating the inverse of an invertible matrix uses only addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $A$ is an invertible real matrix and let $A^{-1}=U+iV$, where $U$ and $V$ are real. Then $$I=A(U+iV)=AU+iAV.$$Since $I$ is real this shows that $I=AU$; hence $A^{-1}=U$, so $A^{-1}$ is real.